# Transform list of dict in dataframe in multiple rows

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

[image]

where the column items is a list of dictionnary with multiple 'item_id' and 'item_name' key. And I would like to split all these informations in the same dataframe like this:

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Comment: With `df` your dataframe you could do `df = df.explode("items", ignore_index=True)`.

Comment: The items element is [{\'item_id\': \'10\', \'item_name\': \'Counter-Strike\'}, {\'item_id\': \'11\', \'item_name\': \'Fifa\'}] and i want to transform this in two differents rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use the [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 2], 'items': [[{'a':'1'},{'b':'2'}], [{'c':'3'},{'d':'4'}]]})

print(df)

print('===============================')

print(df.explode('items').reset_index(drop=True))
```

[image]

Comment: You can incorporate the index resetting into the `.explode` call: `ignore_index=True`.

Comment: ah right @Timus. thank you!! just knew that

Comment: Yeah thank you this command is working well !!